# Handle Bootstrap dropdown event in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I have markup for twitter bootstrap dropdown like below

```
<div class="dropdown" style="width: 300px !important;">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
Source
</button>
<div class="dropdown-menu" id="SelectMe">
   <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">CLE</a>
   <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">SQL</a>
   <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">FFILE</a>
   <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">SampleAPI</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Now, added click event in dropdown using jquery as below

```
 $('.dropdown-menu a').click(function () {           
    alert("Hi")
  });
```

My click event is working but, I am not able to update the selected value in dropdown. How to do it?

Comment: do you want to set the selected text as button text?

Comment: @Kiranramchandran yes

Comment: check the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('.dropdown-menu a').click(function () {           
    $('button').text($(this).text());
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="dropdown" style="width: 300px !important;">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
Source
</button>
<div class="dropdown-menu" id="SelectMe">
   <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">CLE</a>
   <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">SQL</a>
   <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">FFILE</a>
   <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">SampleAPI</a>
</div>
</div>
```

use `$('button').text($(this).text());` to set value to button.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$('.dropdown-menu a').click(function () {           
    $('button[data-toggle="dropdown"]').text($(this).text());
});
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/v7s3wrk8/)